# jQuery UI Draggable - how to change css of original element?

Tags: jquery

I need to change font color of original element, after a copy of it being dragged. How should I do that?

```
jQuery("#tools-container .fieldset-item").draggable({
            revert: "invalid",
            helper: "clone", 
            cursor: "move",
            connectToSortable: ".fieldset-content .sortable",
            stop: function(event,ui) {
            // change helper css   
            }
        }  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You would use the `css` function.

For example:

```
$(this).css("font-color", "#ff0000");
```

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/css/